# PowerShell passing function as parameter

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have two PS scripts (1 main script and 1 as a module).

Main script uses code like:

```
Write-Host "Press Y to continue"
Execute (ConstructSshSessions)
```

Where `Execute` is a function that asks the question to continue and execute the script in the function `ConstructSshSessions`. If the users does not type a `Y` then the main scripts skips the function `ConstructSshSessions`.

Module uses code like:

```
Function Execute($function)
{
    $response = read-host
    Write-Host "You typed: $response"
    if ($response -eq "Y")
    {
        $function
    }
    Remove-Variable response
}
```

When I execute the code `Excecute (ConstructSshSession)` it first runs the script that creates the SSH sessions and then asks the user to continue. So that is clearly not my intention but I do not see the error.

I would like that it asks the users if it may continue and then execute the script that is beeing send as a parameter to the function `Execute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend separating prompting for a response from actually reading the response. I wouldn't recommend passing a function name to some `Exec`-like invocation routine either.

Wrap the confirmation routine in a function that returns a boolean value and invoke the function as the condition of an `if` statement.

```bsh
function ConfirmStep($msg) {
    $title = 'Confirm Step'

    $yes = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&Yes'
    $no  = New-Object Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription '&No'
    $options = [Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($no, $yes)
    $default = 1  # $yes

    [bool]$Host.UI.PromptForChoice($title, $msg, $options, $default)
}

if (ConfirmStep "Construct SSH sessions?") {
    ConstructSshSessions
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sounds like a solid answer. I recently started scripting and could you explain your code more to a beginner? I do not completely understand what the code is doing.

Comment: I already figured it out with your code. Thank you very much. This wil work perfectly.

Comment: Could you explain to me why you would not recommend my way of doing so I can learn from my mistakes?

Comment: You distribute things that belong together (prompt and reading the input) across different sections of your code. That just obfuscates your code. Also, always ask yourself "what do I gain by delegating a function call". If the answer is "nothing" (like in this case): don't do it.